# Firebase Firestore database chat app pagination when tap on the message textfield it automatically scrolls up and not scroll down to the end of list

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, firebaseui

this is code of paginating data from firestore , here i am using a library called firebase_ui_firestore ^1.5.15 from pub.dev,pagination works fine but here the issue is when i tap on the textfield it automatically scrolls up the list , here i always want the list to be bottom for chat app, but for the first time when we click to the chat page it displays the list and scroll at bottom part of list and works as expected ,but the issue only happens when we click on the textfield or send any message the list scrolls up.

is this any library issue? or logical error please help.

here my main aim the list is always at the bottom when we trying to message someone or tap on the keypad or textfield.
here below i am pasting the code of chatpage.

```
class _ChatAppState extends State<ChatApp> {
  final TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();
  final ChatService _chatService = ChatService();
  bool isImageSelected = false;
  bool isSendingImage = false;
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  XFile? image;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _messageController.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _scrollToBottom());
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ThemeManager.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ChatScreenAppBar(
              senderName: widget.name, avatarUrl: widget.profileUrl),
          Expanded(child: _buildMessageList()),
          TextField(
            onMessageSent: (text) {
              sendMessage();
              _scrollToBottom();
            },
            onImageSelected: (selectedImage) async {}, messageController: _messageController,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  /// send chat message.
  void sendMessage()async{
    try{
      if(_messageController.text.isNotEmpty)
      {
        await _chatService.sendMessage(widget.userId,
            widget.currentUserId,
            _messageController.text,'recieverEmail','text','gp-01');
        _messageController.clear();
      }else{
        log('its empty');
      }
    }catch(e)
    {
      log("send Error: ${e.toString()}");
    }

  }
  _scrollToBottom() {
    if(_scrollController.hasClients)
    {
      _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
    }
  }

  Widget _buildMessageList() {
    List<String> ids = [widget.currentUserId, widget.userId];
    ids.sort();
    String chatRoomId = ids.join("_");
    return FirestoreQueryBuilder(
      pageSize: 5,
      query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('chat_rooms')
          .doc(chatRoomId)
          .collection('messages')
          .orderBy('TimeStamp',descending: true),
      builder: (context, snapshot, index) {
        print("currrent index $index");
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error ${snapshot.error}');
        }
        if (snapshot.isFetching) {
          return const Center(child:  CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        print("firebase docs ${snapshot.docs}");
        List<Message> allMessages = snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
          return Message.fromFireStore(doc);
        }).toList();
        // Group messages by date

        return GroupedListView<Message, DateTime>(
            controller: _scrollController,
            reverse: true,
            order: GroupedListOrder.ASC,
            floatingHeader: true,
            elements:allMessages.toList(),
            groupBy: (message) =>DateTime(
              DateTime.parse(message.timeStamp.toDate().toString()).year,
              DateTime.parse(message.timeStamp.toDate().toString()).month,
              DateTime.parse(message.timeStamp.toDate().toString()).day,
            ),
            itemComparator: (item1, item2) => item1.compareTo(item2),
            sort: false, //
            groupHeaderBuilder: (Message message) {
              final formattedDate =
              formatMessageDate(DateTime.parse(message.timeStamp.toDate().toString()));
              return SizedBox(
                height: 40.h,
                child: Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Text(
                      formattedDate,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: ThemeManager.primaryBlack),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, Message message) {
              // WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _scrollToBottom());
              int messageIndex = allMessages.indexOf(message);
              final hasEndReached = snapshot.hasMore &&
                  messageIndex + 1 == snapshot.docs.length &&
                  !snapshot.isFetchingMore;
              print("has reached the end: $hasEndReached");
              if(hasEndReached) {

                print("fetch more");
                snapshot.fetchMore();
              }
              String messageId = snapshot.docs[messageIndex].id;
              return Align(
                alignment: message.receiverId == widget.userId
                    ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.w, vertical: 5.h),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      message.receiverId == widget.userId ? Dismissible(
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        confirmDismiss: (direction) async {
                          bool shouldDelete = await Dialogs.showDeleteConfirmationDialog(context);
                          return shouldDelete;
                        },
                        onDismissed: (direction) async{
                          _chatService.deleteMessage(widget.currentUserId, widget.userId, messageId);
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            TextMessageContainer(message: message,
                              senderId: widget.currentUserId,
                              receiverId:widget.userId,),
                            SizedBox(height: 5.h),
                            Text(
                              DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateTime.parse(message.timeStamp.toDate().toString())),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12.sp,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                color: ThemeManager.secondaryBlack,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ):Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          TextMessageContainer(message: message,
                            senderId: widget.currentUserId,
                            receiverId:widget.userId,),
                          SizedBox(height: 5.h),
                          Text(
                            DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(DateTime.parse(message.timeStamp.toDate().toString())),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12.sp,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              color: ThemeManager.secondaryBlack,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
        );

      },
    );
    
  }
  String formatMessageDate(DateTime? dateTime) {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final yesterday = now.subtract(const Duration(days: 1));

    if (dateTime?.year == now.year &&
        dateTime?.month == now.month &&
        dateTime?.day == now.day) {
      return "Today";
    } else if (dateTime?.year == yesterday.year &&
        dateTime?.month == yesterday.month &&
        dateTime?.day == yesterday.day) {
      return "Yesterday";
    } else {
      return DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dateTime!);
    }
  }
}
```

i don't know is there any issue in this library or my code logic , i am new to this.
my main aim is the list always at bottom end like the chat app, when we tap on  textfield or sending message its always need to be bottom.

chat textfield class code

```
class TextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String)? onMessageSent;
  final Function(XFile)? onImageSelected;
  final FocusNode? focusNode;
  final TextEditingController messageController;

  const TextField({super.key, this.onMessageSent, this.onImageSelected,required this.messageController,
    this.focusNode
  });

  @override
  State<TextField> createState() => _TextFieldState();
}

class _TextFieldState extends State<TextField> {
  XFile? image;
  bool isAttached = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        isAttached
            ? Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.w),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              if (isAttached) ...[
                SizedBox(height: 10.h),
                SizedBox(height: 12.h),
              ],
            ],
          ),
        )
            : const SizedBox.shrink(),
        Container(
          height: 72.h,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.w, right: 18.w),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isAttached = !isAttached;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/icon.png",
                    width: 22.w,
                    height: 23.h,
                    color: isAttached
                        ? Theme.primaryColor
                        : Theme.inactivateColor,
                  )),
              SizedBox(width: 16.w),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  focusNode: widget.focusNode,
                  maxLines: null,
                  controller: widget.messageController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        color: ThemeManager.secondaryBlack),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    final messageText = widget.messageController.text;
                    if (messageText.isNotEmpty) {
                      widget.onMessageSent!(messageText);
                      widget.messageController.clear();
                    }
                  },
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage:
                    const AssetImage("assets/images/ellipse_gradient.png"),
                    radius: 22.5.r,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/send_icon.png",
                      height: 24.h,
                      width: 30.w,
                    ),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAttachOption(String text, ImageSource source) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.w, top: 13, bottom: 13),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          color: ThemeManager.primaryWhite,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Image.asset("assets/images/images_attach.png"),
            SizedBox(width: 20.w),
            Text(              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.sp,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: Theme.primaryBlack),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
}
```

Message model class code

```
class   Message implements Comparable<Message>{
  final String? senderId;
  final String?  receiverId;
  final String? message;
  final String? messageType;
  final Timestamp timeStamp;
  final String? groupId;

  Message({
    required this.senderId,
    required this.receiverId,
    required this.message,
    required this.messageType,
    required this.groupId,
    required this.timeStamp,
});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'senderId': senderId,
      'receiverId': receiverId,
      'message': message,
      'messageType': messageType,
      'TimeStamp': timeStamp,
      'groupId': groupId,
    };
  }

  // Factory constructor to create a Message instance from a DocumentSnapshot
  factory Message.fromFireStore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Message(
        senderId: data['senderId'],
        receiverId: data['receiverId'],
        message: data['message'],
        messageType: data['messageType'],
        timeStamp: data['TimeStamp'],
        groupId: data['groupId'],
    );
  }

  factory Message.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Message(
      senderId: map['senderId'] as String,
      receiverId: map['receiverId'] as String,
      message: map['message'] as String,
      messageType: map['messageType'] as String,
      timeStamp: map['TimeStamp'] as Timestamp,
      groupId: map['groupId'] as String,
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Message{senderId: $senderId, receiverId: $receiverId, message: $message, messageType: $messageType, timeStamp: $timeStamp, groupId: $groupId}';
  }

  @override
  int compareTo(Message other) {
    return timeStamp.compareTo(other.timeStamp);
  } // converted to map

}
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution need to remove the scrollController listener from initstate and also need to remove _scrollToBottom function ,no need to control the textfield also, the list scroll end at the with the help of groupedListview with reverse true option.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  //  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _scrollToBottom()); - need to remove the code from here.
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ThemeManager.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ChatScreenAppBar(
              senderName: widget.name, avatarUrl: widget.profileUrl),
          Expanded(child: _buildMessageList()),
          TextField(
            onMessageSent: (text) {
              sendMessage();
//              _scrollToBottom(); - need to remove the code from here also
            },
            onImageSelected: (selectedImage) async {}, messageController: _messageController,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

no need to use the scrollToBottom function , the GroupedListview libray's reverse true option will help to scroll the list at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

In your `build` method, you are using `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_)` to scroll to the bottom of the list when the widget is built.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _scrollToBottom());
// rest of the build method 
}
```

That means the chat starts at the bottom (where the latest messages are), but it does not handle other interactions like message send or text field focus.
Since `_scrollToBottom` is called in multiple places already (like after sending a message), I would remove the automatic scrolling from the build method, to avoid unnecessary scrolling on every frame build.

---

> > Do you think that, in your case, the keyboard's appearance is causing the scroll issue?
>
> I think yes because when only touches the textfield it scrolls up.

When the keyboard appears, it changes the available screen space, which can cause scrollable views to adjust their positions. In a chat application, you typically want the most recent messages to remain visible when the keyboard is opened.

Try and use the [`flutter_keyboard_visibility` package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility) to listen for keyboard visibility changes. When the keyboard appears, adjust the scroll position to make sure the latest messages stay visible.

Add `flutter_keyboard_visibility` to your [`pubspec.yaml`](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec):

```yaml
dependencies:
     flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^5.0.2
```

The `Listener` would be:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart';

class _ChatAppState extends State<ChatApp> {
     late StreamSubscription<bool> keyboardSubscription;

@override
void initState() {
     super.initState();
     keyboardSubscription = KeyboardVisibility.onChange.listen((bool visible) {
          if (visible) _scrollToBottomDelayed();
     });
}

@override
void dispose() {
     keyboardSubscription.cancel();
     super.dispose();
}

void _scrollToBottomDelayed() {
     Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300), _scrollToBottom);
}

void _scrollToBottom() {
     if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
          _scrollController.animateTo(
               _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
               duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
               curve: Curves.easeOut,
          );
     }
}

// Rest of your widget code
}
```

Make sure the `ListView` accounts for the keyboard's presence by adjusting its padding: the last message won't be hidden behind the keyboard.

```dart
Widget _buildMessageList() {
return ListView.builder(
     controller: _scrollController,
     reverse: true,
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
     itemCount: messages.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
     // Message item builder code
     },
);
}
```

Make sure the scroll position is adjusted when the `TextField` gains focus, in case the keyboard visibility listener does not catch it in time.

```dart
final FocusNode _messageFocusNode = FocusNode();

@override
void initState() {
     super.initState();
     _messageFocusNode.addListener(() {
          if (_messageFocusNode.hasFocus) {
          _scrollToBottomDelayed();
          }
     });
}

@override
void dispose() {
     _messageFocusNode.dispose();
     super.dispose();
}

// Make sure to set the focusNode in your TextField
TextField(
     focusNode: _messageFocusNode,
     // other TextField properties 
),
```

---

The [OP Nns_ninteyFIve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12669460/nns-ninteyfive) adds in the comments:

> I found the solutions need to remove the `scrollController` listener from `initstate`, and also need to remove `_scrollToBottom()` function, list scroll end at the help of `groupedListview` with `reverse` set to `true` option.

Removing the `ScrollController` listener and the `_scrollToBottom` function while relying on the `GroupedListView`'s inherent behavior with `reverse` set to `true` is a valid approach, especially for a chat application where the newest messages are typically shown at the bottom.

- By removing the listener from the `ScrollController` in the `initState`, you prevent any additional or unwanted scroll behavior that might have been introduced by manual scroll control.
- Not using `_scrollToBottom` means that you are relying on the default scrolling behavior of your list view, which can be more natural and less prone to unexpected behavior, especially in the context of keyboard appearance and focus changes.
- Setting `reverse` to `true` in your `GroupedListView` automatically handles the scrolling to show the latest messages at the bottom of the list. That is a common practice in chat UIs as it mimics the natural flow of conversation.

Your `_ChatAppState` class would be something like:

```dart
class _ChatAppState extends State<ChatApp> {
  final TextEditingController _messageController = TextEditingController();
  // No need for a custom ScrollController
  // final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _messageController.dispose();
    // _scrollController.dispose(); // No longer needed
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Remove any method that manually handles scrolling like _scrollToBottom

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // rest of your Scaffold code 
      body: Column(
        children: [
          // other widgets 
          Expanded(child: _buildMessageList()),
          // other widgets 
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  // other methods 
}
```

And in the `_buildMessageList` method, you use `GroupedListView` with `reverse` set to `true`:

```dart
Widget _buildMessageList() {
  // setup for your query and chatRoomId 

  return FirestoreQueryBuilder(
    pageSize: 5,
    query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('chat_rooms')
        .doc(chatRoomId)
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('TimeStamp', descending: true),
    builder: (context, snapshot, _) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      }
      if (snapshot.isFetching) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      List<Message> allMessages = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Message.fromFireStore(doc)).toList();

      return GroupedListView<Message, DateTime>(
        // No need for a custom ScrollController here
        // controller: _scrollController,
        reverse: true, // That keeps your latest messages at the bottom
        elements: allMessages,
        groupBy: (message) => DateTime(
          message.timeStamp.toDate().year,
          message.timeStamp.toDate().month,
          message.timeStamp.toDate().day,
        ),
        // other GroupedListView properties 
      );
    },
  );
}
```

By removing the custom scroll logic, that means there is no need for a custom `ScrollController` or `_scrollToBottom` method, as `GroupedListView` takes care of displaying the most recent messages at the bottom.

The widget structure is simplified, leading to potentially fewer issues related to scroll behavior, especially when interacting with the keyboard or sending messages.

Comment: thanks for your effort , i found the solution need to remove the scrollController listener from initstate and also need to remove _scrollToBottom function ,no need to control the textfield also, the  list scroll end at the with the help of groupedListview with reverse true option.

Comment: @Nns_ninteyFIve Great, well done, and upvoted: I was busy making a summary of your conclusion in my edited answer, so I did not see your answer at first. Let me know if I got anything wrong.